# Mysterious SELECT COUNT(*) appearing in my controller for has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I'm unable at the moment to track down when I started seeing a `SELECT COUNT(*)` call in my development log but it is happening and there doesn't seem to be a reason for it. I'd like to know if this is normal and/or why it is happening. I don't think it's a major problem but why have an extra call to the database if I  don't need it.

In my controller I have

```
def some_action
  @activities = user.activities
end
```

In the `User` class, I have that it `has_many :activities`

and when I call this action, my log output is

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = 1
Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."user_id" = 1
```

All I can tell you for sure is that it didn't use to do that `SELECT COUNT(*)` call and as far as I can tell, there is nothing trying to get that count.

I'm using Rails 3.2.6 and PostgreSQL 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason for the count query is due to Rails' lazy loading and the order in which I'm using my data.

While I iterate over all the `@activities`, the first thing I do with the instance variable in my view template is check if there are any to go through. If not I display something different to the user.

`@activities.empty?` is performing the count and comparing it to 0 which is more efficient than loading all the records into an array and then checking that. I can optionally change my action to be

```
@activities = user.activities.all
```

which prevents the COUNT call and loads all records before constructing the view.